# Testing a MQTT Broker By Connecting 100,000s of Clients

Tags: linux, multithreading, mqtt, emq, mqtt-vernemq

I have been working on MQTT protocol for quite some time. This protocol would be used by the organisation for sending acknowledgment messages to each client separately.

In the use-case, there is only 1 'publisher' client which publishes acknowledgment messages to 'subscriber' clients subscribed to their unique topics

To make sure that the broker is largely bug-free and can scale easily in future, I have been trying to test Emqx and Vernemq open-source brokers by trying to connect at least 50,000 clients to them.

However, I am not able to create those many connections. My Ubuntu 18.04 
 instance (8 core CPU, 15 GB RAM) on the Google Cloud fails to make any more successful connection after around 300-400.

I have tried making the following changes: 
ulimit -n 64500  (for allowing these many file descriptors since every socket connection would require a file descriptor)

Please help me in making over 50,000 connections. Should I run 'n' number of threads and run the total_clients/total_threads clients under loop on each thread?

or should I create one thread for every client connection?

What should I do?

The following message appear on the "$SYS/#" topic once the clients start getting disconnected even though there is no disconnect data packet being sent by the client side. 
$SYS/brokers/emqx@127.0.0.1/clients/112/disconnected {"clientid":"112","username":"undefined","reason":"closed","ts":1536587647}

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
from threading import Lock
import time



print_lock = Lock()
def s_print(str):
    print_lock.acquire()
    print(str)
    print_lock.release()


def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    client_id = userdata["client_id"]
    if (rc == 0):
        s_print("connected " + client_id)
        client.subscribe(client_id, 2)

def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
        client_id = userdata["client_id"]
        s_print("disconnected: " + client_id + " reason " + str(rc))



def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    topic = message.topic
    payload = str(message.payload)
    s_print("Recieved " + payload + " on " + topic)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    n_clients = int(input("Enter no. of clients:    "))

    for i in range(n_clients):
        client_id = str(i)
        s_print(client_id)
        userdata = {
                "client_id"  : client_id
            }

        client = mqtt.Client(client_id=client_id, clean_session=True, userdata=userdata)
        client.on_connect  = on_connect
        client.on_disconnect =on_disconnect
        client.on_message = on_message
        client.connect("35.228.57.228", 1883, 60)
        client.loop_start()    
        time.sleep(0.5)    

while(1):
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Edit the question to include the error messages from the brokers and the clients when the connection failures happen. Also adding the code for the client would be useful. At the moment we would just have to guess

Comment: done. please check out the code.

Comment: You are hitting hurdle #1 in IoT: learning the platform (in this case, just EMQTT or Verne) in order to configure it to support your requirements (you are adding hurdle #2: a test environment). We did 20k and 50k connections respectively 2 years ago https://gambitcomm.blogspot.com/2016/06/mimic-mqtt-simulator-interoperates-with.html . After that, you will have to do performance tests to see if it handles what you throw at it.

Comment: You are not keeping any reference to the clients after starting them. Best guess python is garbage collecting them.